# Local variables in a dictionary function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to handle the below requirement. As a beginner to Python programming, I couldn't get out of the issue which am facing in declaring the variables. I have a huge XML that I need to open and create three dictionaries out of it.

Here are my programming steps.

1. Open the file using the built-in open function
2. Read each line from the object created above
3. Between certain tags, I need to search for a pattern and fill the data into the dictionary.

The XML file looks like

```
<tag_1>
    name=(pattern1)
    age=(pattern1.1)
    company=(pattern1.2)
<\tag_1>

<tag_2>
    name=(pattern2)
    age=(pattern2.1)
    company=(pattern2.2)
<\tag_2>

<tag_3>
    name=(pattern3)
    age=(pattern3.1)
    comapany=(pattern3.2)
<\tag_3>
```

and so on, with repeated above tags.

From each tag above, i need to create 3 dictionaries like:

```
dict1[pattern1]['age']=pattern1.1
dict1[pattern1]['company']=pattern1.2
```

Similarly for dict2, & dict3 as well.

Created a dictionary function, with passing arguments as line, dictionary.

```
for line in file.readlines():
    dict_instance(line, dictionary_1 )
    dict_instance(line, dictionary_2 )
    dict_instance(line, dictionary_3 )



def dict_instance(line, object):
    #ON TAG START (i have this condition set in my code)
    if re.search(r'name=(.*)', line):
        name=re.search(r'name=(.*)', line).group(1)
    if re.search(r'age=(.*)', line):
        age=re.search(r'age=(.*)', line).group(1)
    if re.search(r'company=(.*)', line):
        company=re.search(r'company=(.*)', line).group(1)
    #ON TAG END (i have this condition set in my code)
    object[name]={}
    if not age:
        object[name]['age']=age
    if not company:
        object[name]['company']=company
```

Each tag of data should go in each dictionary, like tag1 to dict1, tag2 to dict2 and tag3 to dict3.

Now my question is how do I can create the "name", "age" & "company" variables local to each dictionary, if I create global variables, these will mix up in all three dictionaries which creates incorrect data in it.

Please ignore if any indentation issues in the above.

Comment: Is dict_instance a function? I'm missing the `def` keyword but it seems to be a function.

E: Also, you seem to call it 3 times for each line you read, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Variables inside the function are local to the function

Comment: (Readers generally won't ignore indentation issues - if there is an error in the presentation of your question, please correct it. If this is wrong here but not in your actual code, readers will give you the wrong advice).

Comment: Oops my bad, for missing the def keyword, is there a better way to handle this rather passing each line to three function calls. And the variables are not considering as local variables by default getting the unbound local error exception. The good thing of this forum is it will not allow to pose a question if we have a indentations errors, so there are no such issues hoping so.

Comment: Why do you need 3 dicts? One for each `tag`?

Comment: Yes @EricDuminil, also the pattern for name variable will be different for two tags among three,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the requirements. But here are some methods which might be helpful:

```
xml_content = """<tags>
<tag_1>
    name=(pattern1)
    age=(pattern1.1)
    company=(pattern1.2)
</tag_1>

<tag_2>
    name=(pattern2)
    age=(pattern2.1)
    company=(pattern2.2)
</tag_2>

<tag_3>
    name=(pattern3)
    age=(pattern3.1)
    company=(pattern3.2)
</tag_3>
</tags>
"""
from xml.etree import ElementTree
document = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_content)
```

You can iterate over the tags and get the desired information:

```
for tag in document:
    print(tag.tag)
    print(tag.text)
    print(tag.text.split())
    print(dict(line.split('=') for line in tag.text.split()))
    print("---------------------")
```

It outputs:

```
tag_1

    name=(pattern1)
    age=(pattern1.1)
    company=(pattern1.2)

['name=(pattern1)', 'age=(pattern1.1)', 'company=(pattern1.2)']
{'name': '(pattern1)', 'age': '(pattern1.1)', 'company': '(pattern1.2)'}
---------------------
tag_2

    name=(pattern2)
    age=(pattern2.1)
    company=(pattern2.2)

['name=(pattern2)', 'age=(pattern2.1)', 'company=(pattern2.2)']
{'name': '(pattern2)', 'age': '(pattern2.1)', 'company': '(pattern2.2)'}
---------------------
tag_3

    name=(pattern3)
    age=(pattern3.1)
    company=(pattern3.2)

['name=(pattern3)', 'age=(pattern3.1)', 'company=(pattern3.2)']
{'name': '(pattern3)', 'age': '(pattern3.1)', 'company': '(pattern3.2)'}
```

If you want one big list or one big dict:

```
def tag_to_dict(tag):
    return dict(line.split('=') for line in tag.text.split())

[tag_to_dict(tag) for tag in document]

{tag.tag:tag_to_dict(tag) for tag in document}
```

Which return:

```
[{'name': '(pattern1)', 'age': '(pattern1.1)', 'company': '(pattern1.2)'},
 {'name': '(pattern2)', 'age': '(pattern2.1)', 'company': '(pattern2.2)'},
 {'name': '(pattern3)', 'age': '(pattern3.1)', 'company': '(pattern3.2)'}]
```

and

```
{'tag_1': {'name': '(pattern1)',
  'age': '(pattern1.1)',
  'company': '(pattern1.2)'},
 'tag_2': {'name': '(pattern2)',
  'age': '(pattern2.1)',
  'company': '(pattern2.2)'},
 'tag_3': {'name': '(pattern3)',
  'age': '(pattern3.1)',
  'company': '(pattern3.2)'}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eric Duminil for your effort and time, but i am looking the dictionary format to be as,

tag1 = {pattern1 : {age :  pattern1.1,
                               company : pattern1.2}}
tag2={pattern2 : {age : pattern2.1,
                            company : pattern2.2}}
tag3 ={pattern3 : {age : pattern3.1,
                            company : pattern3.2}}

Comment: @user3101632 and the two last objects are really close to your desired format. They can still be converted to what you want, without regex or complex logic. You don't need n variables when a list would do.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore the 'XML' module in python